# Include formula in manual Custom Percent Field for one Record Type while manually filling it out for another Record Type

Tags: opportunity, custom-field, record-type, code

I have two Opportunity Record Types, Record Type 1 and Record Type 2. For Opportunity Record Type 1, a custom percent field 'Profit Margin' must be manually input.

For Opportunity Record Type 2, is there anyway to assign a simple formula for the same field, 'Profit Margin'.

Basically the question is, can a percent field calculate one thing for one record type while being left alone and being a manual input field for another record type? If it can, is there a specific code that needs to be included in the CASE or IF statement that would allow for the user to input a % manually for Opportunity Record Type 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Workflow Rule with Evaluation Criteria `Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited` and criteria like:
`RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Record_Type_2'` and use Field Update action with your custom formula for the percentage you always want to use with Record Type 2.
This will be overwriting any value user will put into `Profit Margin` only when record is using Record Type 2.

**Note: Do not forget that value for percent field is set as 1 and is shown as 100%**

Comment: Oleksiy, when I try to go into an opportunity now and change a field, an Error pops up: A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this record. Contact your administrator to resolve it. Division undefined. My formula is: Total_Profit__c  /  Total_Budget_del__c . This workflow is causing the issue because it's dividing by 0 when necessary fields aren't filled out. Can the formula be edited to avoid this issue? If so, can you help me out with the edit?

Comment: Use `IF( BLANKVALUE( Total_Budget_del__c, 0)  =  0, 1,  Total_Profit__c / Total_Budget_del__c)`. You can replace 1 with any 0 to 0.99 value you want to use for `Profit Margin` when `Total_Budget_del__c` is 0 or not set

Comment: Thank you, this is going to help me exponentially going forward for any BLANKVALUE issues. It worked!

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is not strictly possible. The way I'd work around it is:

Create a field with label "Profit Margin" and name "Profit_Margin_rt1__c" for Record Type 1. Show it on the page layout and don't show the formula field.

Then set the formula field to

```
IF( RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Record_Type_1',Profit_Margin_rt1__c,<formula to calculate profit margin>)
```

and show only the formula field on Record Type 2's page layout. This allows you to only have one field per record type, but use just that one formula field for reporting, queries, calculations, etc. regardless of record type.

Comment: beat me to the punch, I had typed up something very similar.

Comment: Thank you, what type of field would Profit_Margin_rt1__c be?

Comment: ... percentage presumably.